# How to embed multiple files to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python

If we make .exe file using single python file, we can use the application on some other device only by transfering the .exe  file
but,

If we are making a project consisting of 2 or more python files.

Main py file - main.py

others bar.py, foo.py

And I'm using #other files by importing into main.

It doesn't work

The .exe file is working ok when main.py is absent, but in absence of other .py files(foo.py or bar.py)
it doesn't work.

How to make it work only by transferring the exe and not any other file

Comment: Do you need to include `foo.py` and `bar.py` including `main.py` to a singe exe file?

Comment: How did you create the exe, what commands did you use?

Comment: Please consider adding a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

For more than two python files just include them one after separated by space. Execute the following code,

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py foo.py bar.py
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import pkg_resources.py2_warn --onefile one.py two.py three.py
```

Comment: may you also suggest how to include the additional text files containing some secret information, while making th exe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package instead:

```
pip3 install auto-py-to-exe
```

Once successfully installed, go to terminal and open with:

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

In my experience it handles complete folders and directories, packaging them into one .exe file. That is the requirement here I believe.